React useState is null after trying to set an array of objects
day tasks are not being set properly
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const userTasks = async () => {
    if (auth && loginStatusID) {
      const todaysTask = localStorage.getItem("TodaysTasks");

      console.log(todaysTask);

      if (todaysTask !== null) {
        const daytask = JSON.parse(todaysTask);
        setTasks([daytask]);
      } else {
        Axios.get(
          `http://localhost:3001/tasks/podoDB/getTask?userID=${loginStatusID}`,
        )
          .then((response) => {
            setTasks(response.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error Getting task:", error);
          });
      }
    }
  };

  userTasks();
}, [auth, loginStatusID]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(tasks);
}, [tasks]);

Tried
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, daytask}));

Returns:
[{"taskID":4012,"task":"hjfksdj","date":"2024-04-12T00:00:00.000Z","descrip":"mw,mds"},{"taskID":4014,"task":"jvkfndklfew","date":"2024-04-12T00:00:00.000Z","descrip":"edwre"},{"taskID":4011,"task":"jkfner","date":"2024-04-19T00:00:00.000Z","descrip":"refrwefr"},{"taskID":4013,"task":"sdjk","date":"2024-04-25T00:00:00.000Z","descrip":"sdkdk"}]
ToDoList.js:98 updated null

ToDoList.js:98 updated null should return the parsed object array
console.log(daytask)

Returns:
0: {taskID: 4012, task: 'hjfksdj', date: '2024-04-12T00:00:00.000Z', descrip: 'mw,mds'}
1: {taskID: 4014, task: 'jvkfndklfew', date: '2024-04-12T00:00:00.000Z', descrip: 'edwre'}
2: {taskID: 4011, task: 'jkfner', date: '2024-04-19T00:00:00.000Z', descrip: 'refrwefr'}
3: {taskID: 4013, task: 'sdjk', date: '2024-04-25T00:00:00.000Z', descrip: 'sdkdk'}


How exactly is the state "not being set properly"?  What specific debugging observation are you making which indicates this?

Don't mix await and .then when dealing with a promise. It just makes things harder to understand

What is this? "ToDoList.js:98 updated null should return the parsed object array"? Is that part of an error message? An IDE warning?

When i console log "tasks" after the use effect it returns null and not the parse array from local storage. Also I forgot to remove the await with .then but I fix that.

It's the useEffect(() => {       console.log(tasks);      }, [tasks]);  when I try to check if it was set

Have you verified the contents of dayTask? Is it possible that it's null because it can't be parsed as JSON?

yes the content it returns is a parsed array of object

if it's getting changed then that part of the code works fine, since it starts life as a [], and if your setter call didn't fire, it would stay an empty array. So the problem is that you are update the value, by literally setting it to null: did you check to see what's in response.data? Because your code seems to just blindly copy that value over, instead of first verifying that it's valid data.

@HazardousHanzo: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates this problem?  (Even off-site if the Stack Snippets don't allow the functionality you need.)  And indicate specifically in that observable example what problem you are referring to?

The code works fine. I have simplified it and put it into this sandbox:
sandbox link
The only thing I can think of is if your stored state is somehow not able to parse correctly with JSON.parse(), as this would cause a null value to be put into tasks. Either that, or the error is happening outside of the code you have shown us.
Simplified version:
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const userTasks = async () => {
      const todaysTask = '["test"]';

      console.log(todaysTask);

      if (todaysTask !== null) {
        const daytask = JSON.parse(todaysTask);
        setTasks([daytask]);
      }
    };

    userTasks();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tasks);
  }, [tasks]);

Output (with Array(1) containing your new tasks, since you wrapped it in an extra array during setting):
["test"]
[]
["test"]
[]
[Array(1)]


Yea, that’s where I am having issue even though it gets parsed from the local storage but still sets it as null. Which todaysTask returns a parsed array after I log it.

@HazardousHanzo then, is there something outside of the code you have shown us that is causing it to be null? because as we see above, the code you have shown us works fine as is.

Fixed the issue by taking a different approach, which was sorting and filtering the axios response.data to match with the local storage content
